# OPC Client server: Error establishing a connection: BadNotConnected

Tags: c#, .net-standard, opc-ua

I am not able to connect opc client. As you can see session's properties not intializing properly and also ApplicationName even UaApplication object(m_application) have all values. I am new in OPC, So please guide me on this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# library you're using. Is anything already establishing a secure channel through which the session can be opened?